# Динамически изменить фон textview (не цвет, а рисунок)

Tags: android, textview, drawable

Есть боковое меню и его разметка:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/listTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/list_group_title"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/head"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Здесь есть строчка:

```
    android:background="@drawable/head"
```

Которая задает фон меню. Как динамически через Java изменить этот фон? Как изменить цвет я знаю:

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
                        tv.setBackgroundColor(R.color.icon_film);
```

А что делать, если мне нужна картинка с `drawable`? Поменять "`color`" на "`drawable`" не даст результата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `setBackgroundResource(int resId)`

```
TextView tv = ...;
tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.SOME_RES);
```

Comment: Да, уже увидел, спасибо.